# To validate the dropdown fields of multiply rendered single component

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxt3

I have a component say return card
in which i have used two custom dropdown components

Also I am using return card component in page

We are using vee-validate to validate forms

I am using two variable to assign the defineComponentBinds for field reference and passing it to the return card component

The problem is :

I am rendering the return card component using v-for
when validated it is applying for all components, even trying with index
it must apply only to those selected one and also the dropdown to those selected one

Project: nuxt3

Thanks!

Comment: Please include code, not just description of code, in your question.  Review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)